# JNI stale local reference error accessing the caller object

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I can't get rid of this error message

> JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0x... (index ...)

I'm trying to access from native the `isInterrupted()` method of the JNI caller class, which is a Java thread. The thread loop is entirely native, spawns other pthreads and holds mutexes. I need a way for the main Android activity to inform the thread that it should stop e.g. by Java's `interrupt()` at the first safe moment.

The scenario is quite simple and clean, nothing else happens between the lines:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
  public native static int native_world_entry();
  public void run() {
    native_world_entry();
  }
  static {
   System.loadLibrary("mylib");
  }
}
```

The native code being the following:

```
jint Java_..._1entry(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
  //jobject jj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, thiz);
  jclass sclass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Thread");
  jmethodID inted = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, sclass, "isInterrupted", "()Z");
  LOGI("Checking");
  jboolean status = (*env)->CallBooleanMethod(env, thiz, inted);
  ...
}
```

All good untill `CallBooleanMethod()` as previous calls are successful and "Checking" is displayed.
I've tried to add the commented line and change `CallBooleanMethod()`'s argument accordingly but the error is the same.

Besides the error I don't catch the reason why a global reference is needed in this case.. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because native_world_entry is static. So thiz is not MyThread istance. It is MyThread class instance.
Add extra param to native_world_entry method to pass thread handler explicitly, e.g. native_world_entry(this).

P.S. Also you can use Thread.currentThread() to get current thread.

Comment: Great catch. Now it works with the local reference, both with a non-static native method and with the current thread as explicit parameter. Thanks.